# Navigation Item Icon sizes for all devices

Tags: android, android-navigation, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

I have completed my app. In this App I am using navigation view. It looks good on normal devices but in larger devices like Tablet 7' and tablet 10', the images in navigation drawer are screwed.

> **My problem**

The Images that I am using in navigation drawer (which is navigation view in fact) showing as the items . Take a look below

drawer.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/inbox"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_inbox_black"
            android:title="@string/inbox_string" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/starred"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_star_black"
            android:title="@string/starred_string" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/sent_mail"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_send_black"
            android:title="@string/sent_mail_string" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/drafts"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_drafts_black"
            android:title="@string/draft_string" />


        <item
            android:id="@+id/allmail"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_email_black"
            android:title="@string/all_mail_string" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/trash"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete_black"
            android:title="@string/trash_string" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/spam"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_error_black"
            android:title="@string/spam_string" />

    </group>
</menu>
```

and For supporting muliple screens and devices I am using the following sizes in following folders

> 1> HDPI  =  48*48  2> Mdpi  =  32*32  3> xhdpi  =  64*64  4> xxhdpi  =
>   96*96  5> xxxhdpi  =  128*128  6> tvDpi  =  96*96
>
> But its still screwing on large devices , I replaces a larger icon in
>   the 
>   ** drawable-tvdpi  with 128. prior i was using 96** but still the images compress

I Do not know what I am doing wrong, and why it is only looking bad on large devices like tablet 7' and tablet 10' where as it is looking good on normal devices.

Please help. Tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Link of the tuto http://www.android4devs.com/2015/06/navigation-view-material-design-support.html for info. How do you find the resources like "ic_inbox_black" ?

Comment: what do you mean by that ?

Comment: I mean, where are they from ?

Comment: its in the tutorial what you need to know about these